# Internet not available exception in Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I was trying to open Sandbox paypal page from my Laravel application and faced below issue

[image]

This issue came when internet connection was not available. Like we face 404 issue...for that we have 404 blade in View folder.

Is there any way to handle this exception so that we can show a user friendly page to user that Please check your internet connection

It doesn't not works when I write below code:

```
if ($e instanceof \PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException) {
    return response()->view('errors.InternetConnection');
}
```

but it works when I write

```
if ($e instanceof \PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException) {
    \App::abort(404);
}
```

I created a new blade called InternetConnection in error folder

Comment: May be you can use try catch where the paypal call. In exception you use abort(404) function

Comment: So in your **views** folder you have a folder **errors** and inside you have a file **InternetConnection.blade.php** - `views/errors/InternetConnection.blade.php`?

Comment: Yes, InternetConnection.blade.php is in Views/errors folder.

Comment: Both of Your code examples should work in normal conditions. There must be some kind of obvious silly error in Your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for this exception in **App\Exceptions\Handler@render**. Just add this:

```
    if ($e instanceof PayPalConnectionException) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }
```

Comment: It doest no works when I write below code: `if ($e instanceof \PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException) {
            return response()->view('errors.InternetConnection');
        }` but it works when I write `if ($e instanceof \PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException) {
            \App::abort(404);
        }`  I created a new blade called `InternetConnection` in error fodler

Comment: This is just an example of redirecting to a view. You can load any template you want `return response()->view('yourTamplateName', [], 404);`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can! (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#the-exception-handler)

in your App\Exceptions\Handler:

```
...
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof PayPalConnectionException) {
        //my paypal exception
        return response()->view('errors.payPalConnectionError', [], 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Comment: I updated the question with more details. Please check

Comment: What you mean don't work? What response you get? The code you have here works.

Comment: Your line `return response()->view('errors.payPalConnectionError', [], 404);` is not working at all and it shows **ONLY** error page I shown in my query description

Comment: be sure you created a file inside resources/views/errors with the name payPalConnectionError.blade.php

Answer (score 1):

**This will work:-**

you need to create a folder named **errors** if not already exist in **views** and place **blade file named 404.blade.php in it**. and put your error template for 404 error in this blade. laravel will automatically use it when ever a 404 error will occur.

Comment: Yes I have 404 blade in errors fodler. I wrote this code:`return response()->view('errors.404', [], "404");` but it does not show me 404 error page.

Comment: you do not need to return laravel will automatically redirect  404 error to template 404.

Comment: use in your code return view('errors.InternetConnection');

Comment: if I write `return view('errors.InternetConnection');` this, exception is not being handled.

Answer (score 1):

In your app/Exceptions/Handler.php edit render method as:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if($e instanceof ValidationException) return response()->view('errors.abc');
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

**Remember** Don't forget to **USE** the Exception in your Handler.php

Like I am showing abc view for `ValidationException` So I am adding this line in my Handler.php class

`use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;`

Otherwise this won't work.